# What will happen to SEO if a blog has 100K attachment page redirects with 20k published articles?

Tags: seo, redirects, wordpress

Consider that there is an old blog, which has almost 10 or more images in every post they published. As everyone knows, WordPress creates an attachment link for every image we upload in a blog.

For SEO, low-quality pages are the biggest problem, so they redirected all the attachment pages to their respective parent posts or home page. Now there are almost 100K redirects in a blog which has only 20k published posts.

So my question is, will this affect SEO?

Of course, this number looks too large to me. What other ways we can use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a problem because when your blog generates over 100k new attachment pages in a small time frame. Based one of my personal experience when we fixed these attachment pages redirection to parent page with actual image resources links for a client. We saw a ranking boost in our client's website within a month without doing anything else.

The reason can be because it will lookalike thin content pages and also it may be ok if there is good ratio between actual posts and attachment pages.

Also if you use WordPress then there is a solution where you can use "Yoast" seo plugin and it has option to redirect attachment pages to image resources which essentially eliminates all those redundant pages and it's much safer option rather redirecting to parent page.

Comment: Yoast does redirect the pages.  It now redirects then to the image URL.  Previous versions had redirected to a page containing the image.